# Android+jquerymobile+phonegap poor performance compared with iphone / blackberry / nokia

Tags: android, performance, jquery-mobile

I have an Android Web apps using jquerymobile and phonegap.

I already compress js/html, place my scripts at the bottom of the page, and I am still not satisfied with the performance of my apps, especially when my script is doing DOM manipulation.

The response of the touch event is very slow (>2 sec or event more).

Tested with Android Browser/Android Firefox and the results are still the same.

When I compare the performance to the normal desktop browser / iPhone Safari / BlackBerry Browser / Nokia Browser my apps are responsive.

Specifications:

1. Samsung Galaxy Tab II
2. Android ICS 4.0
3. phonegap 1.8.0
4. jquerymobile 1.1.0

Recap of what I have already tried:

- Get to [deviceready](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-first-day-of-phonegapping-get-to.html) faster.
- Minimize / compress JS code using YUI Compressor
- Move script tags to the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Add:

```
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

And to the manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Also, collate and minify the scripts (instead of just minifying) and use .destroy() a lot to keep your DOM trim.

PhoneGap on Android is notoriously slow unfortunately.

Comment: how can i use webview.getSettings..? while phonegap use super.loadUrl

Comment: can u say how to use webciew.getSettings in phonegap